# How does JS know where to continue in the Call Stack?

Tags: javascript, callstack

I'm trying to understand how the Call Stack works after each function is popped.

For example:

```js
function inner() {
  console.log("what happens after inner() is popped from Call Stack?");
}

function outer() {
  inner();
  console.log("how does Call Stack return to this line?");
}

outer();
```

I can tell that `outer()` is the first thing to be pushed to the Call Stack:

```js
TOP of Call Stack
----------------
outer() // not executed. so let's begin at line 1!
----------------
BOTTOM of Call Stack
```

And now, as we get to `inner()` in the first line of `outer()`, the former gets pushed to the Call Stack, so we have:

```js
TOP of Call Stack
----------------
inner() // not executed yet!
outer() // line 1 is on… 
----------------
BOTTOM of Call Stack
```

When `console.log` in `inner()` is executed, `inner()` ends and is popped from the Call Stack, so we have:

```js
TOP of Call Stack
----------------
outer() // line 1 is executed. let's continue with line 2! 
----------------
BOTTOM of Call Stack
```

But **how does call stack know where to continue** when it gets back to `outer()`? How can `outer()` at the top of stack not re-start at the first line? Does it have any memory or data structure like a pointer (that points to the line of outer function)? If so where is it? What if a function is recursed say 100 times, meaning we have 100 stack items, how is JS able to manage all the positions and know where to continue?

Comment: I just want to check whether you’re specifically interested in the V8 engine (or some other JIT compiler for JS) or if this is a more general question about evaluation strategies in programming languages? An author of a simple interpreter doesn’t even really _need to_ manage a call stack, while AFAIK on a machine-code level the way subroutines are run and their effects on registers are very similar _across_ high-level languages (i.e. it’s not very JS specific).

Answer (score 1):

The call stack doesn't just store the function to return to, but also the particular location within that function.

It also stores the values of local variables inside the function. This is essential to make recursive functions work properly.

Note that all this is an implementation detail of the JavaScript VM, and it could be implemented in various ways. For example, the return location could be a memory address after JIT-compiling the JavaScript to machine code. Or the function could be inlined, leaving no stack frame at all.

Answer (score 1):

A call stack is a mechanism for an interpreter (like the JavaScript interpreter in a web browser) to keep track of its place in a script that calls multiple functions — what function is currently being run and what functions are called from within that function, etc.

When a script calls a function, the interpreter adds it to the call stack and then starts carrying out the function.
Any functions that are called by that function are added to the call stack further up, and run where their calls are reached.
When the current function is finished, the interpreter takes it off the stack and resumes execution where it left off in the last code listing.
If the stack takes up more space than it was assigned, a "stack overflow" error is thrown.

```
function greeting() {
// [1] Some code here
sayHi();
// [2] Some code here
}
function sayHi() {
return "Hi!";
}

// Invoke the `greeting` function
greeting();

// [3] Some code here
```